# Java ArrayList<Object[]> to Object[][]

Tags: java, arrays

I have data in the format

```
List<Object[]> data = new ArrayList<Object[]>();

for(Something s : SomeList) {
    Object[] tempList = { s.test, s.test2, s.test3 };

    data.add(tempList);
}
```

So I have an `ArrayList` of `Objects[]`. Now I want to get that `ArrayList` of objects into an `Object[][]` so I have the data in the format

```
Object[][] data = { { test, test2, test3 }, { test4, test5, test6 } };
```

but I'm not sure how to do that.

The `ArrayList` step isn't important, it's just the direction I took when trying to figure it out. If you have a better way of getting the data to `Object[][]` that's great.

Comment: @mdoran3844 - Incorrect.  `for(Something s : someList)` iterates over each item in a List or Array.  `s.test` and `s.test2` represent the properties of each successive item in the list.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`List#toArray(T[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29):

```
Object[][] array = data.toArray(new Object[data.size()][]);
```

Comment: Cheers to the pleasant surprises waiting to be discovered when one reads the documentation... I was a little surprised that this would work, but I just tested it and it works great. +1

Answer (score 1):

```
Object[][] data2 = new Object[data.size()][]
for( int i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i)
{
    data2[i] = new Object[data.get(i).length];
    for( int j = 0; j < data.get(i).length; ++j )
    {
        data2[i][j] = data.get(i)[j];
    }
}
```